# Averaging different sized (3D)matrices

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have three matrices with dimensions C11a=(1000x12x10), C11k=(1000x12x10), and C1c(1000x12x9). For description lets say they represent (datapoints x exercises x trials). I am trying to find the mean output for each exercise over all three tests but am having trouble due to the different sized matrices. Any help is appreciated! Thanks

What I have so far:

```
1L= mean(C11a);
2L= mean(C11k);
3L= mean(C11c);
left= (3,1L,3L,4L);
Out=mean(left,3)
```

Comment: Do you want to find the mean of each exercise per trial within 1 data set, then find the mean of the exercises across trials within the same data set, then find the mean of the exercises across data sets?

Or do you want something else?

Comment: You have to correct your variable names - starting a variable name with a number (like `1L`) is illegal. Also, it is not clear what is `left= (3,1L,3L,4L)` maybe you mean `left = [3 1L 3L 4L]`? but using it this way you'll have dimension mismatch...

Comment: if the `mean` is not weighted you can just do `mean(A(:);B(:);C(:)....)` for any A,B,C,... matrices...

Comment: I am looking to find the mean of each exercise across the three tests (C11a, C11k, and C1c). My final output should be a 12x1 matrix which will be the average of each exercise. I tried what 'bla' mentioned and am getting the error: 

"Error using mean>parseInputs (line 187)
Trailing string input must be one of 'double', 'native',
'default' or one of 'omitnan', 'includenan'.

Error in mean (line 66)
    [flag, omitnan] = parseInputs(flag, flag2, isFlag2Set);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your objective is to obtain the average of all exercises (vector of size 12) you can cocatenate your three matrices into a big matrix of size 100x12x29

```
big_matrix=cat(3,C11a,C11k,C1c)
```

And then when you run the `mean` command, you can specify over which dimension to run (default is 1), so you have to run it twice, once over the first dimension, then over the third dimension. You can do it at once like this:

```
out=mean(mean(big_matrix),3)
```

Comment: Thanks Noel! 
I did this and the answer I get is a singular value where I am looking for 12 values. It's close- just hasn't preserved the 12 unique exercises

Comment: a singular value?, can you please tell me what `size(big_matrix)` gives you?

Comment: AHA! You were right Noel-I was inserting your suggestion after I had already taken the mean which meant I was taking the mean 3 times instead of 2 (like you suggest)- your question made me go back a take a second look so thanks for your help!